# I have nestjs docker container app. It is running well but when I'm deploying again on server, the uploads folder is removed

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

I have nestjs docker container app. It is running well but when I'm deploying again on server, the uploads folder is removed.

I tried to use docker volume, but something is missing and it is not working for me.

Below is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.10
    ports:
      - ${DATABASE_PORT}:5432
    volumes:
      - ./.data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - type: bind
        source: ./client
        target: /opt/app/client
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
```

Comment: That Compose file doesn't seem to contain anything beyond a database.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

In order to save your files in host machine with docker you have to use `Named Volumes` . with `Named volumes` your files & folders would be persist with restarting container nd are only removed manually with docker cli.
For creating `Named volume` add this command to `docker-compose`:

```
volumes:
   - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: that is already added for postgres dataabase but my uploaded files are removed